# TabControl Border is not hidden when adding the new button(add button) in tabpanel in wpf

Tags: c#, xaml, tabcontrol

In tab control i have to add + button to tab item like in screenshot. I added the plus button to tab panel, when i run the program and selecting the tab item the tab control border is not hidden like normal tab control. please check the attached screenshot for clarity of my question.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="templateRoot"
                            ClipToBounds="true"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0" />
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel
                                x:Name="headerPanel"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TabPanel
                                    x:Name="_HeaderPanel"
                                    Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                    IsItemsHost="true"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
                                <Button
                                    x:Name="addButton"
                                    Width="50"
                                    Height="30"
                                    Background="LightGray"
                                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                    BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
                                    Command="{Binding ChartAddButton_Click}"
                                    Content="+" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="contentPanel"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
```

By adding the plus button to tab panel this will occurs. How to fix this. Please give your suggestion.

[Please refer the updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoiUp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the dotted lines. That's not the border that's being displayed, I think that's the default `FocusVisualStyle` of the Button.

Try setting,

```
FocusVisualStyle = "{x:null}"
```

on the Button.

Comment: I am not mentioned the dotted line. Please refer my updated screenshot.

Comment: Please any suggestions?